# Annotation - Read element value at build-time

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to read the value of an annotation element at ***build time***? For example, if I have the following annotation defined:

```
public @interface State {
    String stage();
}
```

and I annotate a method in a class, like so:

```
public class Foo {
   @State(stage = "build")
   public String doSomething() {
      return "doing something";
   }
}
```

How can I read the ***value*** of the @State annotation element 'stage' at build time, in an annotation processor? I have a processor built as follows:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes(value = {"State"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class StageProcessor extends AbstractProcessor { 
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> elementTypes,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getRootElements()) {
               // ... logic to read the value of element 'stage' from
               // annotation 'State' in here.
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have an annotation processor you can just run apt (annotation processing tool), but I guess the question is, what do you mean by build time?  Do you mean when the code compiles?  Do you mean during the build process?  Do you need help invoking apt for a certain build tool (e.g. Eclipse, Ant, Maven, etc.)?

Comment: During the build process. In other words, when the annotation processor would run. Also, I don't need to run the apt tool as I'm using java 6 which includes native support for annotation processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the best answer as I haven't done this myself, but seeing as it's been 3 hours I'll do what I can.

> Overview of annotation processing
>
> Unless annotation processing is
>   disabled with the -proc:none option,
>   the compiler searches for any
>   annotation processors that are
>   available. The search path can be
>   specified with the -processorpath
>   option; if it is not given, the user
>   class path is used. Processors are
>   located by means of service
>   provider-configuration files named
>   META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
>   on the search path. Such files should
>   contain the names of any annotation
>   processors to be used, listed one per
>   line. Alternatively, processors can be
>   specified explicitly, using the
>   -processor option.

So it appears that you need to create a file named `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` in your `META-INF/services` folder that lists the names of your annotation processors, one per line.

EDIT: So then I believe the code to read the annotations would be something like...

```
    for (Element element : roundEnv.getRootElements()) {
        State state = element.getAnnotation(State.class);
        if(state != null) {
            String stage = state.stage();
            System.out.println("The element " + element + " has stage " + stage);
        }
    }
```

A real-world example of an annotation processor can be found [here](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/hibernate/jpamodelgen/trunk/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/).

Comment: Thanks for the dig out!I'm very surprised I haven't received a definitive answer yet. I have the steps setup that you outlined above. What I really need however, is a way read the annotation elements.

Comment: Just access the fields of the annotation directly. e.g. String stage = state.stage();